# Can not refactor in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I can not access the refactoring menu, my code compiles and runs, and I can't use the shortcut; it says that the refactoring  extract method is not available at this time and I do not have the right click option nor the top menu.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your code running when you try to access the refactoring menu ? Editing won't be possible if you are debugging.

Comment: I had it in debug mode and I couldn't access the menu so I switched it to Release and I still can not access the Refactoring option and no my code has completed when I tried to run it.

Comment: Okay well, I feel stupid, Visual Studio does not support refactoring for C++ and I didn't see that anywhere in the documentation :|